# angularjs: check if value exists in array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var a = [ { id:1}, {id:2} ];
var b = {id:1};
var res = a.indexOf(b._id) == -1;
console.log(res);
```

I want to check if `b._id` is in `a[]`.
**Note:** `a[]` is an array of objects

Comment: `a.map(x => x.id).indexOf(b.id) != -1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```js
    var a = [{ id:1}, {id:2}];
    var b={id:1};
    var arrayWithIds = a.map(function(x){
                               return x.id
                          }); // get new array contains all ids 
    var present = arrayWithIds.indexOf(b.id) != -1 // find the b.id array
    console.log(present);
```

Here is the reference for [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function of JavaScript to check it. It will compare `id` and its `value` as well.

Below is working code:

```js
var a = [{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 2
}];
var b = {
  id: 1
};

if (a.map(x => x.id).indexOf(b.id) != -1) {
  console.log("Available");
} else {
  console.log("Not available");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
var a = [ { id:1} ,{id:2} ];
var b={id:1}
console.log(a.findIndex(function(obj){return obj.id=b.id}))
```

indexOf works when you are dealing with indexed arrays not with array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code:

```js
var a = [ { id:1}, {id:2} ];
var b={id:1}

function findMatch(element) {
  return element.id === b.id;
}

console.log(a.findIndex(findMatch));
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way is using `.find` function.

```js
let a = [{
    id: 1
  }, {
    id: 2
  }],
  b = {
    id: 1
  },
  obj = a.find(function(itm) {
    return itm.id == b.id;
  });

console.log(obj)
```

And also using `.findIndex` function to get just index of item in array.

```js
let a = [{
    id: 1
  }, {
    id: 2
  }],
  b = {
    id: 1
  },
  objIndex = a.findIndex(function(itm) {
    return itm.id == b.id;
  });

console.log(objIndex)
```

And for getting all objects with that condition use `.filter` function.

```js
let a = [{
    id: 1
  }, {
    id: 2
  }],
  b = {
    id: 1
  },
  objArr =  a.filter(function(itm) {
      return itm.id == b.id;
  });

console.log(objArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.map() function compare id and its value and return a Boolean value if map as commented by @Slava Utesinov

```js
var a = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}];
var b = {id: 1};
if(a.map(x => x.id).indexOf(b.id) != -1){
  console.log("Exists");
}else{
  console.log("Not exists");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var a = [ { id:1} ,{id:2} ];

var b={id:1}

console.log(a.find(x=>x.id==b.id))// return matched record

var a = [ { id:1} ,{id:2} ];

var b={id:3}

console.log(a.find(x=>x.id==b.id)) //return undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) of AngularJS

```
var a = [{id:1}, {id:2}];
var b = {id:1};

var found = false;
var filterResult = $filter('filter')(a, {id: b.id}, true);

if (filterResult.length > 0) {
    found = true;
}
```